# Organising DAO Classes

Tags: class, associations

I am wondering the **best** way to organise DAO classes when it comes to the classes associations.

For example. Lets say you have a Customer table and a Order Table and you want to access the orders associated with the customer, where is the best place to have the method, for example, getCustomerOrder(int customerid, int orderid)?

Customer Class?
Order Class?
CustomerOrder class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use none of those actually.
Customer Class, Order Class, and CustomerOrder class are all classes about the business domain.
The getCustomerOrder(int customerid, int orderid) method is about how you are persisting your data. For many different reasons (like [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), etc..., etc..) I'd put in in a class that deals with persisting the data into wherever you want to persist it. One option could be a DBPersistenceSystem or something like that. This will also help, since the code for getCustomerOrder(int customerid, int orderid) or getCustomer(int customerid) or getOrder(int orderid) will be pretty similar. If you put all of them in the same class or set of classes,you'll end up with a better design.

Answer (score 0):

- Looks like you are using a CustomerOrder class (table in the middle).
- The relationship between Customer and Order is C *..* O} (many-to-many).
- I recommend putting the `getCustomerOrder(int cusomerid, int orderid)` in this class since at runtime the class instance the values needed for the formal parameters should be within scope of both the Customer class and the Order class.
- The referential integrity of the related table schema should have the constraints to enforce this usage if CustomerOrder is the table in the middle.

I like this link for a good example of pivot or table in the middle

[pivot table](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/mysql-many-to-many-table-mapping-pivot-tables.html)